# Constructing continuous functions with prescribed preimage

Tags: general-topology

Given two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, and open sets $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$, when is it possible to construct a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ such that $f^{-1}[V] = U$. What about $f^{-1}[V]$ is a nonempty subset of $U$? The specific case I am interested in is when $Y$ is in fact normed, but I am curious about the question in general (e.g. if any separation properties of a topological space might be able to guarantee this).

I came across this question when thinking about constructing continuous functions that can violate some other continuity property with respect to an algebra. In particular when $Y$ is a metric space, for an algebra of sets $\mathcal A$ on $X$ and some point $x \in X$, we can define a function to be $\mathcal A$-continuous if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $A_1, \dots, A_n \in \mathcal A$ such that $\bigcup A_i$ is a neighborhood for $x$ and $\mathrm{diam}(f[A_i]) < \varepsilon$. If we would restrict to just one set instead of finitely many and we replace $\mathcal A$ with the topology on $X$, this is precisely continuity, so this is a sort of "multi continuity". I am curious which functions are continuous but not $\mathcal A$-continuous.

Comment: $f^{-1}(V) \subset U$ is easy: $f$ can be a constant function whose image is any point in $Y \setminus V$.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I realize that was a bit silly and not actually helpful. I would really like if for any given open $U \subseteq X$ I could find some continuous $f$ such that $f^{-1}[B(0, 1)] = U$

Comment: The standard extension theorems are the Tietze extension theorem and Urysohn's lemma. However, these are a little different from what you want, as they are typically stated for maps from closed sets into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to construct something like this using a Urysohn's lemma argument but didn't succeed.

Comment: The choice of $U, V$ is definitely important, preimages of continuous functions preserve certain properties e.g. being clopen. So this question is dubious to have an answer, or in other words, direction for us to be able to give an answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: That is fair... how about when $V = B(0, 1)$ in the case $Y$ is a Banach space? I feel I should be able to say something there, at least for $f\inv[V]$ being a nonempty subset of $U$. Honestly it seems a tricky problem, but perhaps there is a way to get around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that a *cozero set* is a complement of *zero set* i.e. $Z$ is a zero set if there exists continuous $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f^{-1}[\{0\}] = Z$. Every open set is a cozero set in $T_6$ space, and all metric spaces are $T_6$ spaces.

**Theorem 1.** If $U\subseteq X$ is a co-zero set and $V\subseteq Y$ is non-empty proper open set, $Y$ is path-connected, then there is continuous $g:X\to Y$ with $g^{-1}[V] = U$.

*Proof:*

Since $U\subseteq X$ is a cozero set, then we can find continuous $f:X\to [0, 1]$ such that $U = \{x\in X : f(x) < 1\}$.

Take $y\in V^c$ and $x\in V$. Take path $w:[0, 1]\to Y$ with $w(0) = x, w(1) = y$, let $t_0 = \inf\{t : w(t)\in V^c\}$, then $s(t) = w(t_0\cdot t)$ is a path satisfying $s(1)\in V^c, s[[0, 1)]\subseteq V$. Indeed, take $t_n\in [0, 1]$ with $t_n\to t_0$ and $w(t_n)\in V^c$, then $s(1) = w(t_0)\in V^c$ since $V^c$ is closed.

Lastly let $g(x) = s(f(x))$, then $$x\in g^{-1}[V] \iff s(f(x))\in V\iff f(x) < 1 \iff x\in U \ \square$$

*Remark 1.* If $U\subseteq X$ is not cozero, then there's no continuous $g:X\to [0, 1]$ with $g^{-1}[[0, 1)] = U$, yet $[0, 1]$ is path-connected, so we can't drop the assumption of $U$ being co-zero in above theorem.

*Remark 2.* $Y$ needs to be at least connected, for otherwise there is non-empty proper clopen $V\subseteq Y$ so that there's no continuous $g:[0, 1]\to Y$ with $g^{-1}[V] = [0, 1)$.

*Remark 3.* If $Y = \{0\}\times [-1, 1]\cup \{(x, \sin(1/x) : 0 < x \leq 1\}$ is the topologist's sine curve and $V = \{(x, \sin(1/x) : 0 < x \leq 1\}$, then there's no $g:[0, 1]\to Y$ with $g^{-1}[V] = [0, 1)$ since then necessarily $g(1) = (0, t)$ for some $t\in [-1, 1]$ but $V\cup \{(0, t)\}$ is not path-connected. Since $Y$ is connected, it's not enough to assume that $Y$ is connected in above theorem.

*Remark 4.* Let $A = \{(x, \sin(1/x)-2) : x\in (0, 1)\}\cup \{1\}\times [-3, 3]$ and $B = \{(x, \sin(1/(1-x))+2 : x\in (0, 1)\}\cup \{0\}\times [-3,3]$, and $Y = A\cup B$. If $V\subseteq Y$ is a non-empty proper open subset of $Y$, $U\subseteq X$ is cozero, then since $A, B$ are not open in $Y$, either $A\cap V$ or $B\cap V$ are proper non-empty open sets in $A$ and $B$ respectively. Without loss of generality assume $A\cap V$ is a non-empty proper open set in $A$, the other case being similar. Since $A$ is path-connected, there exist continuous $g:X\to A\subseteq Y$ with $g^{-1}[V] = g^{-1}[A\cap V] = U$. The space $Y$ is not path-connected but it satisfies the statement of the theorem.

**Corollary.** If $X$ is $T_6$ and $Y$ is path-connected, then for every open $U\subseteq X$ and non-empty proper open $V\subseteq Y$ there exists continuous $g:X\to Y$ with $U = g^{-1}[V]$.

**Theorem 2.** Let $Y$ be Sierpiński space. Then for every open $U\subseteq X$ and proper non-empty open $V\subseteq Y$ there is continuous $g:X\to Y$ with $g^{-1}[V] = U$.

*Proof:* Indeed, if $Y = \{0, 1\}$ and $\tau_Y = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, Y\}$, then $V = \{1\}$ is the only non-empty proper open subset of $Y$, and letting $g = 1_U$ be the characteristic function of $U$ i.e. $$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0\text{ for }x\in X\setminus U \\ 1\text{ for }x\in U\end{cases}$$ then $g$ is continuous and $g^{-1}[V] = U$.

*Remark.* Sierpiński space is path-connected so it satisfies theorem 1. Theorem 2 shows that something stronger holds in this case.